# запрос на управление файлами и их чтение

Tags: java, android

не получается запросить доступ к управлению и просмотр файлов просто нет запроса и приложение нечего не просит пробовал по разному не выходит.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.DownloaderGBByKakao"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

и джава

```
package com.kakao.downloadergbbykakao;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Проверяем, есть ли у приложения разрешения на чтение и запись файлов
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Если нет разрешений, запрашиваем их у пользователя
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE);
        } else {

       
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE) {
            // Проверяем результат запроса разрешений
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Разрешения получены.
          
            } else {
                // Разрешения не получены.
                Toast.makeText(this, "Разрешения не предоставлены", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Может это Вам поможет - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51374551/read-and-write-external-storage-permission-isnt-working

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос `targetSdk` из проекта и версию Андроид на которой проверяете.